# Strange IE6 Link Text Bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I'm working on ironing out some bugs in IE6 and have this strange one, screenshot here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNKfR.jpg

The last three letters seem to repeat on a new line.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: I have seen this before in my projects, but I forget how I solved it.... Try setting "zoom:1;" on the style of that box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the "IE6 Duplicate Characters Bug".

In short, `<!-- comments -->` are making IE6 go crazy.

Read about it here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html

Also here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie6-ghost-text-bug-with-multiple-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use overflow:hidden; on your box.